# List with multiple element types and multiple objects

Tags: java, list, object, element

I need your help on the following for Java:

I have a List which contains different objects and each objects has three different values (String, int, double).

I want to increase the int value by one. How do I access the int value of an object in this list and increase it by 1?

Thanks for any help!

I tried to do this:

list.set (i, intvalue + 1)

Comment: Could you share your object ? Does your object have getter and setter methods ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.  First, you have to be sure that you're working with an integer value in your list.  If you try to do addition on a type that doesn't support addition, then you'll get an error.  You also get an error if you try to access a position that doesn't exist in the list.

Then, to change an Integer value, you need to first get the current value of the item you want to "change", then add `1` to it, and finally, replace the old item with a new item in the list that has the new value.  Here's an example of how to do all of this, assuming you want to add `1` to the object at position `i` only if that item exists and is an `Integer`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    someList.add("A String");
    someList.add(100);
    someList.add(100.2);

    int i = 1;
    if (someList.size() > i) {
        Object originalValue = someList.get(i);
        if (originalValue instanceof Integer) {
            someList.set(i, (Integer)originalValue + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(someList);
}
```

Result:

```
[A String, 101, 100.2]
```

Note that you have to cast the original value to an `Integer` after pulling it from the list.  The list has to be a list of `Object` since you want to be able to store multiple types of values in it.  Because of this, once you know you're dealing with an `Integer`, you then need to cast the value to `Integer` explicitly to have Java treat it as a numeric value.

Comment: Hi, thanks already! What happens if I have multiple objects within one list so that I can’t access the needed int value by just searching for the object? So it’s list(value1.1, value1.2, value 1.3; value 2.1, value 2.2, value 2.3; value 3.1, value3.2, value 3.3) and I want to for example access value 3.2 in the list and increase it by +1 Thanks for your help :)!

Comment: You can iterate over the list and just compare each value to the value you are looking for.  For example, for each iteration, you could perform the test `Double.valueOf(3.2).equals(x)`.  If you did this, you wouldn't have to first check for `x` being a `Double`, as it's valid for any type to be compared against a `Double` in this way.  For any object that isn't a `Double`, the test will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `list.set()` you put a new object in the place of the previous one (deleting the previous object from the list).

This is not what you need. You need to get the object to then access its property. Let's assume the object whose property you want to access is at index 1. Then you do this:

```
list.get(1).count++;
```

, where `count` is the name of an object's property of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a class called Pojo

```
class Pojo {
  private String str;
  private int integerValue;
  private double doubleValue;

  public Pojo(String str, int integerValue, double doubleValue) {
    this.str = str;
    this.integerValue = integerValue;
    this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
  }

  public String getStr() {
    return str;
  }

  public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = str;
  }

  public int getIntegerValue() {
    return integerValue;
  }

  public void setIntegerValue(int integerValue) {
    this.integerValue = integerValue;
  }

  public double getDoubleValue() {
    return doubleValue;
  }

  public void setDoubleValue(double doubleValue) {
    this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
  }
}
```

And now you have a list of `Pojo` objects wherein you want to increment the value of integer. The following code will work assuming you have access to change/increment the values using `setter` method.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pojo p1 = new Pojo("str1", 1, 1.5);
    Pojo p2 = new Pojo("str2", 2, 2.5);

    List<Pojo> listOfPojo = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);

    List<Pojo> collect = listOfPojo
        .stream()
        .map(pojo -> pojo.setIntegerValue(pojo.getIntegerValue() + 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks already! What happens if I have (String, int, int) instead of (String, int, double? I suspect the getIntergerValue doesn’t work anymore? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `getIntegerValue` is basically derived from the `getter-settor` methods that are generated. So you need to change the name of the settor method to the respective new method and the above code should work fine.